# Why is the page() object NULL for a QT WebEngineView?

Tags: qt, qml

I define a WebEngineView in QML like this:

```
WebEngineView {
    id: webView
    objectName: "webView"
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "http://www.qt.io"
}
```

The page shows fine.  I tried to access the underlying page like:

```
QObject* rootObject = engine->rootObjects().first();
QObject* qmlobj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("webView", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
QWebEngineView* webView = (QWebEngineView*)qmlobj;
qDebug() << "webView->page(): " << webView->page();
```

However page() is NULL.  How do I get the underlying page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWebEngineView` != `WebEngineView`!!!

[WebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html) is a QML type, while [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) is a widget class! I'm honestly surprised your application did not crash.

The C++ implementation of WebEngineView is private, and thus cannot be accessed directly in C++.

You can call methods by using [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) and access properties with [`QObject::property`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property), but checking the WebEngineView documentation reveals, there is no `page` method or property ...

Comment: Sorry *very* new to QT.  I am trying to attach at QWebChannel to the WebEngineView's page.  I guess I cannot use a QML type and have to create a QWebEngineView in C++?

Comment: Have a look at: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#webChannel-prop

Comment: Just read through the documentation and follow the links, this can help sometimes